# Average of top 2

Tags: sql

I would like to get the average of the top2 *limit1* per *policyid*. I need my resulting table to also have *objectid*.

*Limit1* and *objectid* come from the table p_coverage.
*Policyid* comes from the table p_risk. 
The table p_item is a linking table between p_risk and p_coverage.

The way I thought I should build my query is: create a ranking of *limit1* within each *policyid*. Then take the avg top2.

However the ranking doesn't work and give wrong result. My query works if I take columns from ONE table, but as soon as I add joins between them it gives false ranking.

```
SELECT policyid, limit1,  /*pcob,*/ RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY policyid ORDER BY limit1 DESC) AS rn
FROM   (SELECT policyid, limit1/*, pc.objectid ASpcob*/ 
        FROM p_risk pr 
        LEFT JOIN p_item 
          ON pr.objectid=p_item.riskobjectid 
        LEFT JOIN p_coverage pc 
          ON p_item.objectid=pc.insuranceitemid) AS s
        ) AS SubQueryAlias
GROUP BY
        policyid, limit1/*, pcob*/, rn
        ORDER BY rn,policyid,limit1 DESC
```

The table at the end of the picture is what I'd like to have. The first table is the result of the query of Golden Linoff

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results results would really help clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `ROW_NUMBER()` in the subquery and *then* to aggregate and filter in the outer query:

```
SELECT policyid, AVG(limit1) as avg_top2_limit1
FROM (SELECT policyid, limit1,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY policyid ORDER BY limit1 DESC) as seqnum
      FROM p_risk pr LEFT JOIN
           p_item i
           ON pr.objectid = i.riskobjectid LEFT JOIN
           p_coverage pc 
           ON i.objectid = pc.insuranceitemid) AS s
        ) p
WHERE seqnum <= 2
GROUP BY policyid
```

Comment: Thanks! it's getting closer but this is not exactly what I am expecting. Please see the picture I attached to the original post

Comment: Would it be `dense_rank()`? I'm just coming along and skimming so not sure.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to previous comment! I succeed to do what I wanted.  There is the query

```
 select b.policyid, avg(b.limit1) as avg_top2_limit1 from(
 SELECT distinct(policyid) policyid, limit1 
 FROM (SELECT policyid, limit1,
         Dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY policyid ORDER BY limit1 DESC) as 
seqnum
  FROM p_risk pr LEFT JOIN
       p_item i
       ON pr.objectid = i.riskobjectid LEFT JOIN
       p_coverage pc 
       ON i.objectid = pc.insuranceitemid) AS s

 WHERE seqnum <= 2 ) as b
 GROUP BY policyid`
```